# Mongoexport with extra hardcoded columns

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, awk, mongoexport

I have 3 fields in my collection A, B, C. I'm using the following command to export it in csv format.

```
mongoexport --host %s -u%s -p%s --authenticationDatabase %s --db %s --collection %s --query \'%s' --type=csv --out %s --fields A,B,C
```

But the business requirements is such that I need my CSV files to contain 4 columns with one hardcoded column D ( as a part of pipeline not entirely in my control) which contains string "success" written.

My csv needs to look like:

```
A, B, C, D
x, y, z, "success"
```

Currently after running the export, I'm using **awk** to append the fourth column in  the csv, but I was wondering if this could work directly with mongoexport. Another option which I'm thinking of is to write a custom script to write 3+1 columns to csv, basically writing my own export utility helper.

Comment: Not sure about `mongoexport` if awk is OK `awk -F, -v OFS=,  'NR==1{$0=$0 FS "D"} NR!=1{$4="\"Sucess\""}1'`

Answer (score 0):

sed version (my preference in this case):

```
Mongo ... | sed '1 s/$/, D/;1! s/$/, "Success"/'
```

awk version:

```
Mongo ... | awk '{$0 = $0 ", " (NR > 1 ? "Success" : "D")} 7'
```

don't know mongodb function but the best is to query directly including this fixed value as an "extra" field of the request